# Missing 1 digit in time column read excel in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have excel that have format like this

```
| No  | Date     | Time  | Name | ID     | Serial  | Total |
| 1   |2021-03-01| 11.45 | AB   | 124535 | 5215635 | 50    |
```

Im trying to convert excel to pandas dataframe using below code

```
pd.read_excel(r'path', header=0)
```

pandas read the excel successfully however, I found strange result when I see the column time.
the dataframe have below result

```
|  No  | Date     | Time  | Name | ID     | Serial    | Total |
| 1.0  |2021-03-01| 11.4  | AB   | 124535 | 5215635.0 | 50.0  |
```

Column Time is missing 1 digit. is my method to read excel is not correct?

Comment: can you `print(df.head(5).to_dict())` and add it, your method seems fine i think the problem is with the src data.

Comment: This is the dict from my dataframe        {'NO': {0: '1.0', 1: '2.0', 2: '3.0', 3: '4.0', 4: '5.0'}, 'DATE': {0: '2021-03-01', 1: '2021-03-01', 2: '2021-03-01', 3: '2021-03-01', 4: '2021-03-01'}, 'TIME': {0: '13.0', 1: '13.0', 2: '13.0', 3: '13.0', 4: '13.0'}, 'NAME': {0: 'AF ', 1: 'AR ', 2: 'SH ', 3: 'IA', 4: 'GSF'}, 'ID': {0: '1175821', 1: '1175820', 2: '1275820', 3: '1175823', 4: '1175829'}, 'SERIAL': {0: '760000030046980.0', 1: '760000030046981.0', 2: '760000030046982.0', 3: '760000030046983.0', 4: '760000030046984.0'}, 'TOTAL': {0: '1.0', 1: '1.0', 2: '1.0', 3: '1.0', 4: '1.0'}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_excel` is interpreting your dot-separated time as a float, which is quite expected.

I suggest telling read_excel to see this column as a string and convert it to datetime afterwards:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(r'path', header=0, converters={'Time': str})
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format="%H.%M")
```